# Swift JSON API: When certain keys don't have all defined variables, none of the variables pass through

Tags: json, swift

As the question states, below I have a model and a view to show answer1, answer2, answer3, and answer4 from my json data API for each key. However, some of the keys only have answer1 and answer 2, but no answer 3 or 4. For these keys, I am not getting any data to show up at all. I thought that using the if let answer3... would solve this, but it did not. Here is an example json data both with ("1') and without full data ("6"), followed by the code I have been using in swift.

JSON Data

```
"questiondata": {
    "1": {
      "question": "When do you want your plans?",
      "answer1": {
        "logo": "sun.and.horizon.circle.fill",
        "Text": "Tonight"
      },
    "6": {
      "question": "Active or Lowkey?",
      "answer1": {
        "logo": "figure.seated.side.air.lower",
        "Text": "Active"
      },
      "answer2": {
        "logo": "dial.medium.fill",
        "Text": "Lowkey"
      }
```

Swift Code

```
struct ContentViewdos: View {
    @StateObject var model = DataManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let qData = model.response?.record.questiondata.data {
                List(Array(qData.keys), id: \.self) { key in
                    VStack {
                        Text(qData[key]?.answer1.text ?? "no data")
                        Text(qData[key]?.answer2.text ?? "no data")
                        if let answer3 = qData[key]?.answer3 {
                            Text(answer3.text)
                        }
                        if let answer4 = qData[key]?.answer4 {
                            Text(answer4.text)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await model.loadData()
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class DataManager: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var response: APIResponse? = nil
    
    @Published private(set) var length = 0
    @Published private(set) var index = 0
    @Published private(set) var reachedEnd = false
    @Published private(set) var answerSelected = false

    func loadData() async  {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/641f82dcace6f33a22fbec99") {
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                response = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include your data model in the question since that is what it seems like you are having problem with and the sample data you have provided seems incomplete since you claim question 1 is with full data but it has only one answer.

Comment: Rather than dictionaries with dynamic keys I recommend to create the JSON with arrays which is much easier to parse. Even the root key `questiondata` is actually not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data can have `missing` keys, then it is simple to fix.
Based on your previsous question/answer, use the following model for `Quest`,
Note the `Answer?`. Adjust your current code to cater for optional `Answer` as
shown in the example code:

```
struct Quest: Codable {
    let question: String
    let answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4: Answer?  // <-- here
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DataManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // a specific entry
            if let quest = model.response?.record.questiondata.data["1"] {
                VStack {
                    Text(quest.question).foregroundColor(.red)
                    if let answer = quest.answer1?.text { Text(answer) }
                    if let answer = quest.answer2?.text { Text(answer) }
                    if let answer = quest.answer3?.text { Text(answer) }
                    if let answer = quest.answer4?.text { Text(answer) }
                }
            }
            
            Divider().frame(height: 10).background(Color.blue)
            
            // all entries
            if let qData = model.response?.record.questiondata.data {
                List(Array(qData.keys), id: \.self) { key in
                    VStack {
                        if let quest = qData[key] {
                            Text(quest.question).foregroundColor(.red)
                            if let answer = quest.answer1?.text { Text(answer) }
                            if let answer = quest.answer2?.text { Text(answer) }
                            if let answer = quest.answer3?.text { Text(answer) }
                            if let answer = quest.answer4?.text { Text(answer) }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await model.loadData()
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class DataManager: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var response: APIResponse? = nil
    
    @Published private(set) var length = 0
    @Published private(set) var index = 0
    @Published private(set) var reachedEnd = false
    @Published private(set) var answerSelected = false

    func loadData() async  {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/641f82dcace6f33a22fbec99") {
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                response = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let record: Record
    let metadata: Metadata
}

struct Metadata: Codable {
    let id: String
    let metadataPrivate: Bool
    let createdAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case metadataPrivate = "private"
        case createdAt
    }
}

struct Record: Codable {
    let questiondata: QuestionData
}

struct QuestionData: Codable {
    var data: [String : Quest]
    
    struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?
        
        init?(stringValue: String) {  self.stringValue = stringValue  }
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.data = [:]
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)
        container.allKeys.forEach { key in
            if let theQuest = try? container.decode(Quest.self, forKey: key) {
                self.data[key.stringValue] = theQuest
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct Answer: Codable {
    let logo, text: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case logo
        case text = "Text"
    }
}
```